# Get Events from site "Ticket Network"

Tags: php, api, wsdl

I don't know is this right place to ask this question but, I am working with a web site related events. There is a one site named "Ticket Network" (https://www.ticketnetwork.com) which provide events of their site to show on our site.

Following is an API to get details of event from Ticket Network. Actually its a WSDL.

http://tnwebservices-test.ticketnetwork.com/TNWebservice/v3.2/TNWebserviceStringInputs.asmx

To get events using above wsdl, it require parameter "websiteConfigID" which is mandatory. I try to get events using some test values for websiteConfigID like 3121 or 5676 but it return error  "Authorization error: IP 127.00.00.09 (websiteConfigID=5676) is not authorized to use this service. (reference:GetEvents-TN-WEBTEST01-02d04)".

IP given above is example one.

Is any one have any idea about How to get valid "websiteConfigID" for Ticket Network ? Please help if any one know about it.

Comment: You'd probably be better off contacting them directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need an account at TicketNetwork so you can register your IPs and then access the API. Setting up an account is free. Send me an email and I will help you set up an account majeske@ticketnetwork.com. You can learn more here http://ticketnetworkdirect.com/default.aspx. Thanks, Christopher

Comment: How can we know to be announced date/time using event API's XML?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to first register with them and create an account to use their services.

Once that completes, they will then send you the necessary parameters along.

For context, I'm using this service for one of my office projects. Outside help is very limited but they provide a technical team where you can clarify their API.